# Слова с одинаковым написанием и разными ударениями

Tags: омографы

вИдение-видЕние

Ирис-ирИс

клУбы-клубЫ

острОта-остротА

трУсить-трусИть

Comment: А вопрос-то какой?

Answer (score 4):

Что нужно? Если сказать, как называются эти пары слов (но **не словосочетания**), то это **омографы** - одинаковое написание при разном произношении: ма́ло (по количеству) — мало́ (по размеру), ме́ла — мела́,  ме́сти — мести́, ме́ха — меха́, ми́ловать (щадить) — милова́ть (ласкать), мудрёно — мудрено́, ми́лую — милу́ю, му́ка — мука́;

оде́ржим — одержи́м, о́пера — опера́ (сотрудники оперативных служб), о́рган (тела) — орга́н (муз. инструмент);

па́йки — пайки́, па́ли — пали́, па́рить — пари́ть, па́ром — паро́м, пе́кло — пекло́, по́лы (у одежды) — полы́,  по́лки — полки́, по́ра — пора́, по́рты (мн. ч. порт) — порты́ (штаны),  пря́ди — пряди́, пчёлы — пчелы́

и другие.